# Display method not recognized, because of module reference

Tags: axapta, dynamics-365-operations

when creating a new form having VendTrans ax a datasource, the build failed with nine errors. All of these errors are related to **display methods beeing not reconised**. In the end of the error text : Are you missing a module reference.

**I checked the model references, and I made sure that the model Application suite( the model that holds the vendTrand table) is refrenced. 
But these errors dont disapear.**

the error text is for example :

> diaplay method tracenum defined on VendTrans, refrenced in data source
>   'Vendtrans' of form 'VendTransFormCustom', returns type 'TranceNum',
>   which is not recognized. Are you missing a module reference ?

So how can I correct them, and what is a module reference. I never heard about them.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Extended Data Type `TraceNum` belongs to model `Ledger`, so `Ledger` must be added to the list of the referenced packages in the model that you are working in.

```
Visual Studio > Dynamics 365 > Model Management > Update model parameters
```